# How to execute multiple-line selection in the Stata for Linux command line?

Tags: linux, stata

I need to debug my code from the Linux command line. I do not want to run the whole do-file by peforming "do mydofile.do".
I just need to rerun several lines of code (which are saved in the buffer).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run your specific lines in console by copy & paste? It will work if all blocks are placed correctly